# Excel VBA Unable to get the TTest property of the WorkSheetFunction class

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run a TTest formula on two points of data, but I keep getting the error "Unable to get the TTest property of the WorksheetFunction class". Here is my code, where am i going wrong?

```
Sub a()

Dim Z As Double

Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.TTest(Sheet1.Cells(1, 2), Sheet1.Cells(2, 1), 2, 1)

MsgBox "value is " & Z

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first two parameters for `TTest` function have to be ranges/arrays.

```
Sub a()

Dim Z As Double

Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range("A1:A2")

Dim rng2 As Range
Set rng2 = Range("B1:B2")

Z = WorksheetFunction.TTest(rng1, rng2, 2, 1)

MsgBox "value is " & Z

End Sub
```

[image]

**Syntax** 
Also refer this [link](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Excel-Ttest-Function.html)

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the response! I copied your code directly and I am still getting the same error message?

Comment: @user2416002 Please enter arbitrary values in range `A1:B2` and try running the code.

Comment: @user2416002 i have added an image to my answer. Please referesh.

Comment: ok. I am not sure what was previously wrong, but I put in your values and ran - worked! you rocked it man. I appreciate the help!

Comment: While you are helping, I have another question. I have an excel sheet of means already, but and I am looking to compare them. By requiring an array, I have to average two averages (which defeats the purpose). Is there a way to make a singular cell act as an "array" within the ttest function so that it will see a singular value as an array. I know this is a noob question but I am doing my best to learn. Thanks for the help in advance